# Why dynamic .ToString() (string.Format(), Convert.ToString()) returns dynamic and not string?

Tags: c#, dynamic, tostring

This question is for educational purposes only. I have this code that fails at compile time on line where I want to write lines to file. (`File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\processed.txt",contents);`)

Error messages:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from
>   `'System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>'` to
>   'string[]'    C:\hg\PricingEngine\Source\App\Support\PricingEngine.Migrator\Program.cs    49  57  PricingEngine.Migrator
>
> Error 6   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(string, string[])' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\hg\PricingEngine\Source\App\Support\PricingEngine.Migrator\Program.cs    49  13  PricingEngine.Migrator

If I comment out last line and inspect with breakpoint all lines are strings, and everything works just fine.

**Code:**

```
public static void Main()
{
    var t = new List<dynamic>
    {
        new {name = "Mexico", count = 19659},
        new {name = "Canada", count = 13855},
    };

   var stringed =  t.Select(o => string.Format("{0} {1}", o.name, o.count)).Select(o => Convert.ToString(o)).ToList();
   File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\temp\processed.txt", stringed);
 }
```

**What is going on here why dynamic ToString(), string.Format() and Convert.ToString() is dynamic? Am I missing something obvious here?**

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "why dynamic ToString is dynamic", you haven't provided the error message you're seeing, and I'm sure your example is much longer and more complicated than it needs to be in order to demonstrate the issue. (It doesn't help that we need to scroll a huge amount to see all of the expression assigned to `contents`...)

Comment: Yes, I got that much from "it fails at compile time" - but you should include the exact error message, as well as reducing the problem to a minimal example.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing this:`(o => string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", o.country, o.deaths, o.reason, o.relative)).Select(o => Convert.ToString(o))` Aren't you already taking a string..Why are you reconverting to string?

Comment: @arviman to have it as strings and then converting hoping that will do it...

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius - The second select is redundant.

Comment: @arviman I know it is it simpy to ilustrate that no matter how much you toString cast whaterever dynamic comes out and not string, don't you find it counterintuitive?

Comment: @JonSkeet this question is not how do I fix this. Question is why would toString() and string.Format and Convert.ToString() produce dynamic. Just tell me already :)

Comment: Fix the question so it's a minimal example, and I'd be happy to. There's still *way* too much code here, most of which is irrelevant to your actual question.

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, minimized to what is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like your question can really be boiled down to:

```
dynamic d = "x";
var v = Convert.ToString(d);
```

... the compile-time type of `v` is `dynamic`, as shown by hovering over it in Visual Studio, and you'd expect it to be `string`. No need for lists or files.

So, why is this? Basically, C# has a simple rule: almost any operation that uses a dynamic value has a result of `dynamic`. That means it doesn't matter if extra overloads are available at execution time that aren't known at compile time, for example.

The only operations I'm aware of where the result of an operation involving a dynamic value isn't dynamic are:

- The `is` operator, e.g. `var b = d is Foo; // Type of b is bool`
- A cast, e.g. `var x = (string) d; // Type of x is string`
- The `as` operator, e.g. `var y = d as string; // Type of y is string`
- Constructor calls, e.g. `var z = new Bar(d); // Type of z is Bar`

For the simple case of a method call, section 7.6.5 of the C# 5 specification makes it clear that `Convert.ToString(d)` will have a type of `dynamic`:

> An *invocation-expression* is dynamically bound (§7.2.2) if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - The *primary-expression* has compile-time type dynamic.
> - At least one argument of the optional *argument-list* has compile-time type dynamic and the *primary-expression* does not have a delegate type.
>
> In this case the compiler classifies the *invocation-expression* as a value of type `dynamic`.

(As a side-note, the "and the *primary-expression* does not have the delegate type" part doesn't seem to be resolved anywhere, or honoured by the compiler. If you have a `Func<string, string> func = ...; var result = func(d);` the type of `result` still appears to be `dynamic` rather than `string`. I shall look into that...)

Comment: Thanks Jon, and sorry about messy question.

Comment: So I was lying in my bed last night and it still bothers me - why not return string when toStringed - I mean dynamic is still an object and object has toStirng so why not use that, but rather have this different mechanism that is quite counter intuitive. This must be intentional design choice, or could it simply required additional effort to do this for dynamics and Microsoft had better things to do?

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: Even if you call `ToString()`, that could be hidden in a class by a new `ToString()` method returning `int` for example... and note that you're not even calling the virtual `ToString` method here, you're calling `Convert.ToString()`.

Comment: I find this to be utter madness. `myDynamic.ToString()` returns dynamic? Then `ToString()` is a clearly a lie! `Convert.ToString(myDynamic)` returns dynamic? Then `Convert.ToString()` is also clearly a lie! But `myDynamic as string` returns string?  So any conversion fails while any cast succeeds? How can any developer be expected to intuit this?

Answer (score 2):

Because of how dynamics work, the compiler doesn't know the type of `t.name`, and therefore can't find the right overload for the `File.WriteAllLines` method. One solution could be to explicitly cast `t.name` to `string`, but in your case you can use implicit typing for your array and stop using dynamic at all:

```
var t = new[]
{
    new {name = "Mexico", count = 19659},
    new {name = "Canada", count = 13855},
    new {name = "U.K.", count = 3286},
    new {name = "France", count = 2231},
    new {name = "Italy", count = 2201},
    new {name = "Germany", count = 1688},
    new {name = "Jamaica ", count = 1688},
    new {name = "Bahamas ", count = 1538},
    new {name = "Japan", count = 1538},
    new {name = "People's Republic of China", count = 1327},
    new {name = "Spain", count = 995},
    new {name = "Netherlands", count = 904},
    new {name = "Hong Kong", count = 904},
    new {name = "India", count = 904},
    new {name = "Ireland", count = 844},
    new {name = "Republic of China (Taiwan)", count = 693},
    new {name = "Switzerland ", count = 633},
    new {name = "Republic of Korea", count = 633},
    new {name = "Australia", count = 603},
    new {name = "Greece", count = 482},
};
```

Comment: Hi KooKiz, thanks I know how to solve it :) I just don't understand why after `string.Format()` and `Convert.ToString()` it is still dynamic.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius That's actually a pretty darn good question. My guess is that the compiler is just playing safe. Indeed, for `string.Format` it seems obvious that the return type is `string`. But say I have a method `Method` with two overloads and different return types: `int Method(int value)` and `string Method(string value)`. Here, if your parameter is dynamic, then you have no way to know at compile time which one will be called, and therefore what the return type will be. So the compiler just mark it as dynamic.

Comment: Precisely! Still I have a felling Jon knows why - just wouldn't tell ... :) Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius: I try to avoid answering poor questions (which I consider this to be) as an incentive for people to put effort into asking good questoins.